# Why do we read VeZot HaBerachah on Shemini Atzeret?

Tags: torah-reading, simchat-torah, shmini-atzeres, parashat-vezot-habracha

Megillah 31a teaches that the Torah reading for the second day of Shemini Atzeret (observed outside of Israel) is VeZot HaBerachah.

Why is this passage an appropriate reading for Shemini Atzeret?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44627/170