# Why don't we start reading Parshat Bereshis at the beginning of the year, from Rosh Hashana?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, rosh-hashanah-new-year

It just doesn't seem to make sense to me. Why start later?

Comment: See Devarim 11 and Shmot 23

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44627/759